# How can I match a full string in FaunaDB using ContainsStrRegex?

Tags: faunadb

I'm trying to match a full string of digits using the following expression in `Fauna Query Language`:

```
q.ContainsStrRegex("123", "^\d*$")
```

This returns `false`. Just `"\d*$"` seems to work so I would imagine there's a different -1th match pattern. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host language, which looks like JavaScript, is doing string parsing before the pattern makes it into the `ContainsStrRegex` function. `"\d"` means "make a string with this escaped 'd'", which is just "d".

You need to escape the backslash to get it into the string, and subsequently into the function.

```
q.ContainsStrRegex("123", "^\\d*$")
```

Comment: Gotcha. This was in the shell, which is JS, right?

Comment: Yep. Both the Dashboard's shell and `fauna-shell` use the JavaScript driver internally.